# CoreImage - run filter on CPU

Tags: cocoa, core-image

I'd like to run some CoreImage filters on the CPU, instead of the GPU. In the CI documentation, I've discovered that you can express your preference that filters be executed on the CPU by creating a context something like this ([see here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#qa/qa1416/_index.html)):

```
NSDictionary * cpuonlycontextOptions = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSNumber numberWithBool: YES],kCIContextUseSoftwareRenderer,nil];
CGContextRef cgcontext = [[NSGraphicsContext graphicsContextWithBitmapImageRep:rep] graphicsPort];
CIContext * cpu_context = [CIContext contextWithCGContext:cgcontext options: cpuonlycontextOptions];
```

To apply a filter, I'm currently doing this:

```
NSBitmapImageRep * bitmaprep_in;
CGImageRef cg_image_in = [bitmaprep_in CGImage];

CIImage * ci_image_in = [CIImage imageWithCGImage:cg_image_in];

CIFilter * edge_filter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIEdges"];
[edge_filter setDefaults];
[edge_filter setValue:ci_image_in forKey: @"inputImage"];

CIImage * result = [edge_filter valueForKey: @"outputImage"];

NSBitmapImageRep* rep = [[NSBitmapImageRep alloc]  initWithCIImage:result];
```

The problem is, I can't see where or how to set the CPU only CI context. How is this done properly?

Answer (score 0):

This forces CPU rendering:

```
NSDictionary *theCIContextOptions = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], kCIContextUseSoftwareRenderer, NULL];

CIContext *theCIContext = [CIContext contextWithOptions:theCIContextOptions ];
```